# Subtract values from subsequent row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a situation where I need to generate second column by subtracting from the first column. Is there any way to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Is there also an ID column or similar?

Comment: What determines the order? Have you had a look at `LEAD`/`LAG`?

Comment: @jarlh Yes I do have. I have update the question.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want `lead()`:

```
select col1, 
       lead(col1) over (order by col1) - 1
from t;
```

If you want `395` as the final value, you can add a default value:

```
select col1, 
       lead(col1, 1, 396) over (order by col1) - 1
from t;
```

Comment: Values will be dynamic and I cannot set the final value. I am getting Null values at the end.

Comment: @VirenderThakur . . . That is what the first version does.

Comment: Sorry but I am getting last column as NULL. https://pasteboard.co/JMXy7cH.png

Comment: @VirenderThakur . . . Right.  If you don't want `NULL`, you can use the second version or `coalesce()`.

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you cannot use window functions, you can join based on `ID` column:

```
select mt1.col1, mt2.col1 - 1 col2
from myTable mt1
left join myTable mt2 on mt1.Id = mt2.Id - 1
```

You just need to take care of row with maximum `Id` as it will have `null` in second column.